# Unit testing nodejs module using mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, rabbitmq, mocha.js, chai

I have a nodejs app for which I am writing unit tests and I have the following situation : I have a config.js file in which I read multiple parameters from as environmental variables and some certificates to connect to RabbitMQ. I export this configuration as a module.

What I want to do is to create a unit test file which will take test the module in different scenarios and try to achieve a very high coverage percentage.

I have several environments like LOCAL_DEV, DEV, UAT and PROD with several instances of RabbitMQ. For dev for example I connect to RabbitMQ using a key file, in LOCAL_DEV only with username and password, in UAT with a pfx and so on.

The environment variables like process.env.ENO_ENV get injected during deployment and other configuration params I get them via the .env_dev or .env_uat files for example. I get also certificates injected when I do the deployment and the path to them is given in the '.env_' file.

For example, in DEV, I have process.env.ENO_ENV = dev and the .env_dev looks like :

```
RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE = 'tls/dev/rmq-XXX.key'
RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE = 'tls/dev/rmq-XXX.crt'
RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE = 'tls/dev/rmq-dev-ca.crt'
```

The tests are done in Gitlab, where I do not have any certificate file or .env_ file given so I need to mock the process.env.ENO_ENV and the .env_file.

The content of the config.js file :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Load config for the set env
global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);
const eno_env = process.env.ENO_ENV || "";

if (process.env.ENO_ENV == 'dev' || 
  process.env.ENO_ENV == 'local_dev' || 
  process.env.ENO_ENV == 'uat' || 
  process.env.ENO_ENV == 'prod') {    
  require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(global.appRoot, '.env_' + eno_env) });
} else {
  require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(global.appRoot, '.env') });
}

const {
  PORT,
  RABBITMQ_PROTOCOL,
  RABBITMQ_USER,
  RABBITMQ_PASS,
  RABBITMQ_HOSTS,
  RABBITMQ_PORT,
  RABBITMQ_VHOST,
  RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE,
  RABBITMQ_QUEUE,
  RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE,
  RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE,
  RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE,
  RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX,
  RABBITMQ_SSL_PASSWORD,
} = process.env;

let opts = {};

if (RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX) {
  console.log ('RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX : ' + path.join(global.appRoot, RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX));
  opts = {
    pfx: fs.readFileSync(path.join(global.appRoot, RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX)),
    passphrase: RABBITMQ_SSL_PASSWORD,
    ca: [fs.readFileSync(path.join(global.appRoot, RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE))],
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  };
} else if (RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE) {
  opts = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(global.appRoot, RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE)),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(global.appRoot, RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE)),
    ca: [fs.readFileSync(path.join(global.appRoot, RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE))],
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  };
}

const config = {
  app: {
    port: parseInt(PORT) || 8126,
    enoenv: eno_env,
  },
  rabbitmq: {
    protocol: RABBITMQ_PROTOCOL || 'amqps',
    user: RABBITMQ_USER || 'test',
    pass: RABBITMQ_PASS || 'test',
    hosts: RABBITMQ_HOSTS || 'localhost',
    port: parseInt(RABBITMQ_PORT) || 5671,
    vhost: RABBITMQ_VHOST || 'test_virtualhost',
    exchange: RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE || 'test_exchange',
    queue: RABBITMQ_QUEUE || 'test_queue',
    opts,
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

My problem is to achieve the unit test coverage with mocha and chai by using a file called configCert1UnitTest.js :

```
const should = require('chai').should();

process.env['RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX'] = '/test/test.json';
process.env['RABBITMQ_SSL_PASSWORD'] = 'test';
process.env['RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE'] = '/test/test.json';

const config = require('./../config');

describe('env 1', function () {
    // running tests
    it('reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX property, config.rabbitmq.opts.pfx and test.json file correctly', function () {
        try {
            //target = fs.readFileSync(path.join(global.appRoot, process.env['RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX']));
            should.equal( 
                config.rabbitmq.opts.pfx.toString('utf8'), 
                '{\r\n    "property" : "test"\r\n}');
          } catch(e) {
            throw new Error("error reading env RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX property, config.rabbitmq.opts.pfx or test.json: " + e.message);
          }    
    });

    it('reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.ca and test.json file correctly', function () {
        try {
            should.equal( 
                config.rabbitmq.opts.ca.toString('utf8'), 
                '{\r\n    "property" : "test"\r\n}');
          } catch(e) {
            throw new Error("error reading env RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.ca or test.json: " + e.message);
          }
              
    });
  });
  
  delete process.env.RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX;
  delete process.env.RABBITMQ_SSL_PASSWORD;
  delete process.env.RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE;
```

Now, for having the situation where the other IF in the condif.js is covered i wrote the second test case in file configCert2UnitTest.js :

```
const should = require('chai').should();

process.env['RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE'] = '/test/test.json';
process.env['RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE'] = '/test/test.json';
process.env['RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE'] = '/test/test.json';

const config = require('./../config');
  
describe('env 2', function () {
    
    // running tests
    it('reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.key and test.json file correctly', function () {
        try {
            should.equal( 
                config.rabbitmq.opts.key.toString('utf8'), 
                '{\r\n    "property" : "test"\r\n}');
          } catch(e) {
            throw new Error("error reading env RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.key or test.json: " + e.message);
        }    
    });

    it('reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.cert and test.json file correctly', function () {
        try {
            should.equal( 
                config.rabbitmq.opts.cert.toString('utf8'), 
                '{\r\n    "property" : "test"\r\n}');
          } catch(e) {
            throw new Error('error reading env RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.cert or test.json:' + e.message);
          }    
    });

    it('reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.ca and test.json file correctly', function () {
        try {
            should.equal( 
                config.rabbitmq.opts.ca.toString('utf8'), 
                '{\r\n    "property" : "test"\r\n}');
          } catch(e) {
            throw new Error('error reading env RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.ca or test.json: ' + e.message);
          }    
    });

  });

delete  process.env.RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE;
delete process.env.RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE;
delete process.env.RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE;
```

The problem is the tests do not cover the ELSE of the module config.

Commands for testing in my package.json:

```
...
"test": "npx nyc mocha test --exit --timeout 10000 --reporter mocha-junit-reporter",
...
```

Output :

```
PS D:\zzz-api> npx mocha test
global.appRoot : D:\zzz-liveprice-api
RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX : D:\zzz-api\test\test.json


  env 1
    ✔ reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX property, config.rabbitmq.opts.pfx and test.json file correctly
    ✔ reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.ca and test.json file correctly

  env 2
    1) reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.key and test.json file correctly
    2) reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.cert and test.json file correctly
    ✔ reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.ca and test.json file correctly

  Dummy Test
    ✔ First test that should pass

  Bindings Unit Test
    ✔ Should return true if the correct bindings are found for the EUA
    ✔ Should return true if the correct bindings are found for the POWER
    ✔ Should return true if the correct bindings are found for the GAS


  7 passing (534ms)
  2 failing

  1) env 2
       reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.key and test.json file correctly:
     Error: error reading env RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.key or test.json: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\configCert2UnitTest.js:19:19)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)

  2) env 2
       reads env RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.cert and test.json file correctly:
     Error: error reading env RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE property, config.rabbitmq.opts.cert or test.json:Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\configCert2UnitTest.js:30:19)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

I forgot to mention that I set up a test.json file for the tests in my \test directory, which contains '{\r\n    "property" : "test"\r\n}' just to simulate the certificates, which are missing when testing in Gitlab.

Any ideas how to fix this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve my problem by doing the following :

I create a function in my config.js :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
  // Load config for the set env
  global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);
  const eno_env = process.env.ENO_ENV || "";
  ...
  return config;
}
```

Then, in my test file `configUnitTest.js` I moved the constant definition inside the `describe()` method and put it in a `before()` block instead of using it in the beginning of the test file.

Also, mocha tests the rest of the files in the folder `test` and if there is a another test file which reads `const conf = require('../config')();` this will

```
const should = require('chai').should();
const mock = require('mock-fs');
const path = require('path');

describe('Reading config.js - environmental vars 1', function () {
  let conf;
  before('mocking files and process.env vars', function () {        
    ...
    process.env['ENO_ENV'] = 'local_dev';
    conf = require('../config')(); // reads process.env.ENO_ENV
  });
  ...

  // running tests  
  it('TRUE if it reads var process.env.RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX and mocked file test.json', function () {
    ...
  });
  ...
});

describe('Reading config.js - environmental vars 2', function () {
  let conf;
  before('mocking files and process.env vars', function () {        
    ...
    conf = require('../config')(); // reads const eno_env = process.env.ENO_ENV || "";
  });
  ...

  // running tests  
  it('TRUE if it reads var process.env.RABBITMQ_SSL_PFX and mocked file test.json', function () {
    ...
  });
  ...
});
```

I hope it helps others.